# jQuery if statement - can it go first (or must if go after event)?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-animate

I'm struggling to get this to work. I'm creating a series of clickable buttons that bring down menus. I'm looking to make it work as follows:

1. If drop down menus are all hidden - animate height
2. If any one drop down menu is visible - show/hide to toggle between menus

I can do this fine when the animation to one a new drop down menu is same in both scenarios. However, it's not the look I want. I would really like the "toggle" of show/hide when one is already been opened and the animation of the height when opened for the first time (as well as once closed back up). Since I might go a step further and enable drag down/up for initial open and close and swipe left/right to go between dropdown menus once open, it's another reason for needing the separate animations for each scenario.

I tried doing it with the event first, i.e. click() button and if() all :hidden, then do this... click() button and if() :visible, then do other. But that didn't work, the menu just opened and immediately closed (I think because both .click() events were happening back to back because it recognized my if statements simultaneously? Not sure.)

The next attempt, which is what I have below, was trying to wrap each .click() within it's own if statement to define each separately. But as you can see from the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/U3jHf/31/

Doesn't work...

Here is jQuery:

```
//sideUI drop down

if( $('#sideUIContainer').is(':hidden') && $('#sideUISearchContainer').is(':hidden') && $('#sideUIActionContainer').is(':hidden') ){

    $('#navNavigate').click(function(){

            $('#sideUIContainer').show();       
            $('#sideUIContainer, #sideUISearchContainer, #sideUIActionContainer').animate({'height':'504px'});          
            $('#navNavigate').addClass('active');

    }

    $('#navSearch').click(function(){

            $('#sideUISearchContainer').show();     
            $('#sideUIContainer, #sideUISearchContainer, #sideUIActionContainer').animate({'height':'504px'});          
            $('#navSearch').addClass('active');

    }

    $('#navAction').click(function(){

            $('#sideUIActionContainer').show();     
            $('#sideUIContainer, #sideUISearchContainer, #sideUIActionContainer').animate({'height':'504px'});          
            $('#navAction').addClass('active');

    }

};

// toggle drop down when UI open - menu

if($('#sideUIContainer').is(':visible')){

    $('#navNavigate').click(function(){

        $('#sideUIContainer, #sideUISearchContainer, #sideUIActionContainer').animate({'height':'0'}, function(){

            $('#sideUIContainer').hide();
            $('#navNavigate').removeClass('active');

        }); 
    }

    $('#navSearch').click(function(){

        $('#sideUIContainer').hide();
        $('#navNavigate').removeClass('active');

        $('#sideUISearchContainer').show();
        $('#navSearch').addClass('active');

    }); 


    $('#navAction').click(function(){

        $('#sideUIContainer').hide();
        $('#navNavigate').removeClass('active');

        $('#sideUIActionContainer').show();
        $('#navAction').addClass('active');

    }); 

};

// toggle drop down when UI open - search

if($('#sideUISearchContainer').is(':visible')){

    $('#navNavigate').click(function(){

        $('#sideUISearchContainer').hide();
        $('#navSearch').removeClass('active');

        $('#sideUINavigateContainer').show();
        $('#navNavigate').addClass('active');

    }); 

    $('#navSearch').click(function(){

        $('#sideUIContainer, #sideUISearchContainer, #sideUIActionContainer').animate({'height':'0'}, function(){

            $('#sideUISearchContainer').hide();
            $('#navSearch').removeClass('active');

        }); 
    }

    $('#navAction').click(function(){

        $('#sideUISearchContainer').hide();
        $('#navSearch').removeClass('active');

        $('#sideUIActionContainer').show();
        $('#navAction').addClass('active');

    }); 

};

// toggle drop down when UI open - action

if($('#sideUIActionContainer').is(':visible')){

    $('#navNavigate').click(function(){

        $('#sideUIActionContainer').hide();
        $('#navAction').removeClass('active');

        $('#sideUINavigateContainer').show();
        $('#navNavigate').addClass('active');

    }); 

    $('#navSearch').click(function(){

        $('#sideUIActionContainer').hide();
        $('#navSearch').removeClass('active');

        $('#sideUISearchContainer').show();
        $('#navSearch').addClass('active');

    }); 

    $('#navAction').click(function(){

        $('#sideUIContainer, #sideUISearchContainer, #sideUIActionContainer').animate({'height':'0'}, function(){

            $('#sideUIActionContainer').hide();
            $('#navAction').removeClass('active');

        }); 
    }

};
```

Please let me know if I must clarify the above. But hopefully my fiddle and jQuery code helps you guys understand further what I'm trying to do.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your markup doesn't have contents?

Comment: Let me add some to each. So you can tell which menu is which. Sorry about that. But other than that, contents aren't important here... just got bare markup there to facilitate this drop down function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do things the way you have proposed. Maintaining all those separate event handlers will be a pain. Instead, use a data attribute on the nav and jQuery's `data` method to retrieve it. This will let you programmatically select the correct sidebar without separate handlers.

In your handlers you will add an 'active' class to the active nav item. Then check for this class to determine which of three possibilities the user has encountered.

1. No menu currently open. Animate in.
2. Menu currently open. Hide current menu. Show new menu.
3. Same menu clicked again. Animate out.

I dumped your html/css template because it did not contain functional elements to work with and I didn't want to waste time on the non-js portion of the question. The code can still be cleaned up a bit. I got lazy and left a `foo` in there. But it should be more than enough for you to get a working, robust solution out of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/wSFED/4/

```
$('.nav').click( function() {
    debugger;
    var $this = $(this);

    //current menu has been clicked again
    if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
        //however you want to handle this. I collapsed it again
        var $foo = $('#' + $this.data('menu'));
        $foo.animate( {width:0}, 500);        
        $this.removeClass('active');
        return;
    }

    //another menu is already active
    var $active = $('.nav.active');
    if ($active.length) {
        //toggle current clicked item 
        var thismenu = $this.data('menu');
        var activemenu = $active.data('menu');
        var $thismenu = $('#' + thismenu);
        var $activemenu = $('#' + activemenu);

        //hide the old active menu and remove active class from nav
        $activemenu.css( {width:0} );
        $active.removeClass('active');

        //show the new menu and add active class to nav
        $thismenu.css( {width:300} );
        $this.addClass('active');
        return;
    }

    //no menu is active - animate menu in
    var $menu = $('#' + $this.data('menu'));
    $menu.animate( {width:300}, 500);
    $this.addClass('active');


});
```

Comment: THANK YOU! That is perfect. I will have to really study that to see what's going on. I'm pretty simple in my jQuery knowledge, so my approaches are sometimes not the most efficient. I really appreciate the help.